# How can I download a nuget package only for a specific platform?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I've recently added [NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog) into my solution and I've noticed that the `packages\NLog.4.4.12\lib` directory contains the following directories.

- MonoAndroid10
- net35
- net40
- net45
- sl4
- sl5
- wp8
- Xamarin.iOS10

My projects only target .net 4.0 and .net 4.5. How can I get rid of the rest? I searched in the VS 2017 nuget package manager but I couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't but it might be helpful if you say why you want to "get rid of the rest" there may be another solution to your problem

Comment: @phuzi I thought it was obvious, I want to reduce the footprint of my repository, namely by 9 (useless) MBs

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't really be checking in/committing the contents of the packages folder to source control as they can be retrieved any time and they aren't source code. And it makes your repository even smaller.

Comment: @phuzi this has [already been asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/301649/169548) and the answer is "yes and no". Or even more accurately "a matter of taste".

Comment: If you're concerned about the size of your repository then I would think that it would be a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually removed the directories for the platforms that I didn't need. I've opened the solution with VS 2017 and it didn't complain. I've rebuilt the solution, again no complaint. I've reloaded the project that uses NLog, everything was golden. I've opened package manager, it didn't complain either. In all cases the directories did not reappear.

The only hiccup is that running `Update-Package` in Package Manager Console does not restore the previous state. But since I don't care about supporting other platforms in the future, I didn't bother finding a solution.

You can't call it a scientific solution, but since it's better than nothing, it's an answer for now.